# Cadence workflow output on Cadence UI displays the user/password in plain text

Tags: cadence-workflow

I have used the Cadence workflow. 
I pass a struct to the workflow as argument. 
It has some connection details to a service and user password
It is passed to the activities in that workflow as input

When the activity of a workflow completes, the Cadence UI shows activity details with user/password in plain text

Is there a way to stop showing such user/password values for a Cadence workflow activity input/output in the UI? Please help

Comment: Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both Java and Go SDKs use DataConverter class to serialize and deserialize arguments passed to activities and workflows as well as their results. You can override the data converter to encrypt your data using an algorithm of your choosing.